# Python JSON decode getting wrong value

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON decoder set up with a specific decoder function:

```
data.tankDecoder = JSONDecoder(object_hook=tankFromJSON)
```

tankFromJSON:

```
def tankFromJSON(obj):
    print("object", obj)
    humans = [HumanFish(human["name"], human["position"][0],
                        human["position"][1], human["size"])
              for human in obj["humans"]]
    bots = [RobotFish(bot["position"][0], bot["position"][1], bot["size"])
            for bot in obj["bots"]]
    tank = Tank(obj["canvasSize"], humans)
    tank.grass = obj["grass"]
    tank.bots = bots
    print(tank) 
    return tank
```

The JSON I get looks something like this:

```
{
    "canvasSize": 600,
    "newBotOffset": 50,
    "grass": [
        [583, 588],
        ...,
        [409, 575],
        [496, 574]
    ],
    "bots": [],
    "humans": [{
        "name": ["127.0.0.1", 50014],
        "acceleration": [0, 0],
        "maxSpeed": 3,
        "speed": [0, 0],
        "accelerationRate": 1,
        "position": [300.0, 300.0],
        "foodHistory": [],
        "efficiency": 0.4,
        "size": 20,
        "color": "green"
    }],
    "maxBots": 20
}
```

For some reason the value of `obj` in the `tankFromJSON` function becomes the first dictionary in the `humans` list instead of the whole JSON itself.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4):

During decoding the object hook is called once for every JSON object that is encountered. What you are seeing is that the hook is called on inner objects first, and then on the outer objects next as the deserialization unwinds.

In other words, the whole JSON object *is* processed, but any objects it contains are processed first in an inside-out fashion, as this example demonstrates:

```
s = '''
{
    "outer": {
        "middle": {
            "inner": [1, 2, 3]
        }
    }
}
'''

def hook(obj):
    print(obj)
    return obj

decoder = JSONDecoder(object_hook=hook)
decoder.decode(s)
```

The above prints:

```
{'inner': [1, 2, 3]}
{'middle': {'inner': [1, 2, 3]}}
{'outer': {'middle': {'inner': [1, 2, 3]}}}
```

Comment: So the issue is that I have to instantiate each dictionary in the humans array and use that in instantiating the outer object, so how would I go about fixing this?


Keep in mind that decode takes a string and converts it to an object, and I don't know if humans is nonempty, and I can't just decode humans (because it's not a string).

Comment: It sounds as though you might want to avoid using `object_hook`, and simply deserialize to a dictionary. Then write code to convert `humans` to an object of whatever type, and finally to convert the whole thing to an object of whatever type. Ultimately, though, it isn't very clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, so perhaps it would be better to open a thread specifically concerning your new question.